# QGIS Server & custom CRS

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers-2, qgis-server

I'm using QGIS Server and an OpenLayers-based web client (in EPSG:3857). I have a QGIS project that I want to serve with QGIS Server, containing layers in several CRS, including custom ones.

Everything shows up correctly in QGIS, and on the fly projection is enabled. My QGIS project projection is set to EPSG:3857.

On the client, layers with well-known projections (like EPSG:4326, EPSG:3395 in my case) are shown correctly. But layers with custom CRS are not shown at all.

Is that normal? Is there a way to make all layers visible?

Answer (score 0):

The following link may be helpful:
QWC2 is the QGIS Server Web Client which has a lot of custom configuration including CRS options.

https://github.com/qgis/qwc2-demo-app/blob/master/doc/QWC2_Documentation.md#application-configuration-the-configjson-and-jsappconfigjs-files

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).